# Не импортируется moviepy.editor

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

При попытке импорта moviepy.editor Python выдает ошибку:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from moviepy.editor import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timamine/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py", line 110, in <module>
    from moviepy.video.io.preview import show, preview
  File "/home/timamine/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/preview.py", line 10, in <module>
    pg.init()
RuntimeError: SDL compiled with version 2.0.20, linked to 2.24.0
```

Версия moviepy:

```
1.0.2
```

Операционная система:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```